# Multiple Cells per Listview Row?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Found it odd that I haven't seen any other SO's or documentation on this but, I was wondering if it was possible to have a Xamarin Forms Listview (recycle caching strategy, if that makes a difference) with multiple cells per row? Right now we have the listview that simply displays an image at 300 width (10 padding on each side to make it centered). This works great on iPhones, but on the iPad it looks a bit dorky have the amount of whitespace it does (as you can imagine, just a 300 wide image on an iPad.) Is there any way to make a listview contain multiple cells per row? Particularly, if it can be a variable. So on portrait it can be 2, on landscape it can be 3.

XAML:

```
  <ListView x:Name="gridList" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" ItemAppearing="gridList_ItemAppearing">
  </ListView>
```

Code Behind

```
public System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<ViewModels.GridCellViewModel> cells { get; set; }
gridList.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(Classes.CustomGridCell));
gridList.ItemsSource = cells;
```

GridCellViewModel

```
 public class GridCellViewModel
    {
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public string Headline { get; set; }
        public Xamarin.Forms.ActivityIndicator ActivityIndicator { get; set; }
        public bool IsAd { get; set; }        
        public bool AdHasLoaded { get; set; } = false;
        public int collectionIndex { get; set; }
        public int rawCellIndex { get; set; }
        public int numberOfStories { get; set; }
        public DateTime LoadPageDate { get; set; }
        public int StoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

CustomGridCell

```
    layout = new Xamarin.Forms.Grid();
    layout.RowDefinitions.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.RowDefinition { Height = new Xamarin.Forms.GridLength(1, Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star) });
    layout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new Xamarin.Forms.ColumnDefinition { Width = new Xamarin.Forms.GridLength(1, Xamarin.Forms.GridUnitType.Star) });
    layout.Children.Add(LoadingText, 0, 0);
    layout.Children.Add(cellImage, 0, 0);
    layout.HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
    layout.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
    cellImage.HorizontalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
    cellImage.VerticalOptions = Xamarin.Forms.LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand;
    cellImage.WidthRequest = 260;
    cellImage.HeightRequest = 173;
    View = layout;
```

Comment: You mean a WrapPanel? http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2015/04/02/.aspx

Comment: Well, no, I mean a listview. I was wondering if it was possible. Perhaps it's not. I do thank you for sharing that though.

Comment: Indeed... a listview will not cater for that. Hence you need to revert to another control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms.ListView does not support having more than one cell per a row. You can use a [DataTemplateSelector](https://blog.xamarin.com/customizing-list-view-cells-xamarin-forms-datatemplateselector/) to have different cells used based on the row, but that is it.

I would recommend creating this control natively. I will also add that I have never seen an application with a list that had multiple cells per a row. I've seen big cells that have a lot of information in them, but not multiple cells in a row.